# How to check which Operating System?

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, operating-system

How can I check OS version in a batch file or through a vbs in an Windows 2k/2k3 environment ?
You know ... Something like ... : "If winver Win2k then ... or if winver Win2k3 then ....

Answer (score 4):

Run the [ver](http://ss64.com/nt/ver.html) command and parse the string output that it gives you.

Answer (score 3):

you can use vbscript

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colOSes = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOS in colOSes
  Wscript.Echo "Computer Name: " & objOS.CSName
  Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & objOS.Caption 'Name
  Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objOS.Version 'Version & build
Next
```

use the Caption to capture the string you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ver` and `find`.

Example:

```
ver | find "XP"
```